# undefined method for 'image_changed?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I looked through the other solutions on stack. I ran `heroku run rake db:migrate` and `heroku restart` and it didnt work.

```
 def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
      if respond_to_without_attributes?(method, true)
        super
      else
        match = match_attribute_method?(method.to_s)
        match ? attribute_missing(match, *args, &block) : super
      end
    end
    # +attribute_missing+ is like +method_missing+, but for attributes. When
    # +method_missing+ is called we check to see if there is a matching
```

I checked my AddImageToUsers migration file and everything seems to be okay.

```
class AddImageToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
      add_column :users, :image, :string
    end
  end
```

`App\models\user.rb`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable
  has_many :posts
    mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  has_many :comments

  def role?(base_role)
    role == base_role.to_s
  end

end
```

I am not sure where to check next

Comment: Can you post a more complete error message? It would be helpful to see what file is throwing that error. If you paste that error log, we'll have a better place to start. Adding the files in your app that the error may reference would be helpful as well. Your migration looks fine -- so the error is outside of it.

Comment: Actually, the migration looks a little off. It should be `change`, not `changed`. I think that might fix it.

Comment: show `app/models/user.rb` please

Comment: sorry it is ```def change``` it's just a typo when I transcribed it

Comment: Your rake command should be `heroku run rake db:migrate`.

Comment: do you have mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader in User class?

Comment: Yes I posted user.rb above

Comment: You probably forgot to add the permission in UsersController like: params.require(:user).permit(:image, ...)